# Clicking on the html table row's Edit link to populate EditDATA_form field. The tables data are being populated by servlet response to jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I want to populate form field with the table's row data which is populated like this

```
  <table  class="data-table" border="1">
        <tr>
        <td>Student ID</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Year Level</td>
        </tr>

        <c:forEach items="${allStudents}" var="stud">
            <tr>
                <td>${stud.studentId}</td>
                <td>${stud.firstname}</td>
                <td>${stud.lastname}</td>
                <td>${stud.yearLevel}</td>
                <td><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='edit_doc'>Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
            </table>
```

Now I want to write Jquery (which is completely new to me). I have gone through many of example and asked about the same.But the jquery did not work for me.Can any one please tell what to write in scripts tag?Please also do share code if possible.

//form on the jsp

```
   <form name="frm" class="data-form" action="./StudentServlet" method="POST" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Student ID --></strong><input type="text" class='input1'  name="studentId" value="${student.studentId}" /> </td>
                <td><strong>First Name --></strong><input type="text" class='input2' name="firstname" value="${student.firstname}" /> </td>
                <td><strong>Last Name --></strong> <input type="text" class='input3' name="lastname" value="${student.lastname}" /> </td>
                <td><strong>Year Level --></strong><input type="text" class='input4' name="yearLevel" value="${student.yearLevel}" /> </td>
            </tr>   
      </form>
```

//Scripts

```
//what goes here
```

Comment: what do you want to do with the jquery?

Comment: I want to pre-populate the form fields with the data from the html table's row by clicking the edit link.

Comment: I have to define a javascript function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The js code required for the purpose is not complex.

trying Adding these in scripts,

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
$("td", this).on("click", function () {
    var tds = $(this).parents("tr").find("td");
    $.each(tds, function (i, v) {
        $($(".data-form input")[i]).val($(v).text());
    });
});
});
```

Moreover your form happens to be in table tag.Bring it out of the table tag.**Only thing that remains in your table tag is your table.**